# What does 0b1 mean in C++?

Tags: c++

I came across a part of code that I cannot understand.

```
for (unsigned int i = (x & 0b1); i < x; i+= 2)
    {
        // body
    }
```

Here, x is from 0 to 5.

What is meant by 0b1? and what would be the answers for eg: (0 & 0b1), (4 & 0b1) etc?

Comment: [integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), see (4) (since C++14).

Comment: `0b` designates a _binary number_.  `0b1` is the binary number `1`.

Answer (score 7):

`0b...` is a binary number, just like `0x...` is hex and `0...` is octal.

Thus `0b1` is same as `1`.

`1b0` is illegal, the first digit in those must always be `0`.

Comment: So yeah, it's just a fancy way of writing `1`, which any sane individual would do, IMO.

Comment: @PaulSanders - I did not know that being explicit and "context switching" the reader into "bit mode" with visual cues made one less sane.

Comment: It's not that fancy, for it uses a boolean operator in which it might be useful to indicate that it's boolean algebra by using binary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers said, it is the binary representation of the integer number 1, but they don't seem to have fully answered your question. This has a lot of layers so I'll briefly explain each.

In this context, the ampersand is working as a bitwise AND operator. `i & 0b1` is (sometimes) a faster way of checking if an integer is even as opposed to `i % 2 == 0`.

Say you have `int x = 5` and you'd like to check if it's even using bitwise AND.

In binary, 5 would be represented as `0101`. That final `1` actually represents the number 1, and in binary integers it's only present in odd numbers. Let's apply the bitwise AND operator to 5 and 1;

```
 0101
 0001
&----
 0001
```

The operator is checking each column, and if both rows are `1`, that column of the result will be `1` – otherwise, it will be `0`. So, the result (converted back to base10) is 1. Now let's try with an even number. 4 = `0100`.

```
 0100
 0001
&----
 0000
```

The result is now equal to 0. These rules apply to every single integer no matter its size.

The higher-level layer here is that in C, there is no boolean datatype, so booleans are represented as integers of either 0 (false) or any other value (true). This allows for some tricky shorthand, so the conditional `if(x & 0b1)` will only run if `x` is odd, because `odd & 0b1` will always equal 1 (true), but `even & 0b1` will always equal 0 (false).